# How can I stop Ubuntu Dock from extending to the edges?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

By default Ubuntu Dock in Ubuntu 17.10 and later releases always extends to the edges (top-bar-to-bottom if placed on the left or right and left-to-right when placed at the bottom) even when it's not filled with icons.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour (i.e. I want to make the dock-length flexible so that as the number of application icons in the dock increases, it should expand accordingly)?

[image] ➡️➡️➡️ [image]

In other words, is there a way make Ubuntu Dock look like a "proper dock" instead of a side/bottom panel with full-height/width?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
```

To revert to the "panel mode" run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height true
```

Comment: Also, if you want a graphical tool, install dconf-editor, and navigate to the path @pomsky provided (/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock).

Answer (score 2):

Using either the `Gnome Tweak Tool`, or https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, disable the 17.10 built-in `Ubuntu Dock` extension, and install the more configurable `Dash to Dock` extension, and it'll give you the shorter dock you desire.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Comment: I tried disabling Ubuntu Dock using Tweaks and https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ in a live USB session and restarted GNOME shell (Xorg session). It seems they're not working, dock stays active.

Comment: @pomsky I don't know if working in a live USB session makes it reload a gnome session default when restarting gnome, or why that wouldn't work. In a real session, disabling the built-in `Ubuntu Dock` and enabling the `Dash to Dock` extension from extensions.gnome.org works fine, just the way it's supposed to.