# Upgraded Ubuntu 17.10 is not quite the same as the newly installed one

Tags: 17.10, gdm, ubuntu-dock

My ubuntu 17.10 is running with gnome-shell on Wayland. It was upgraded from ubuntu 16.04 which had already had gnome-shell installed and ubuntu unity removed.

The gnome-shell desktop now, however, seems slightly different from a newly installed 17.04 desktop, in that

**1. ubuntu dock**

The ubuntu-dock is not installed by default. I installed it from source and found there is no dock option in the system setting interface. The dock is placed at bottom and cannot be shifted or resized.

**2. login chooser**

There are two login options in the GDM interface, 'Gnome on Wayland' by default, and 'Gnome on Xorg' as alternative, whereas those for a newly installed 17.10 desktop should be 'Ubuntu on Wayland' and 'Ubuntu on Xorg‘.

**3. xorg residual**

I have removed all the xorg components in the system, but there is still a “Gnome on Xorg' option listed in the GDM login chooser.

**What I want**

I want to use ubuntu dock of smaller size placed at left instead of bottom, and to eliminate the Xorg option in the login screen (forgive me for this obsessive-compulsive desire).

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shrink the size of Ubuntu Dock run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height false
```

as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970241/how-can-i-stop-ubuntu-dock-from-extending-to-the-edges).

To place Ubuntu Dock at the left run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock dock-position 'LEFT'
```

To get rid of Xorg entries from the greeter remove/rename (`something.desktop` to `something.desktop.backup` etc.) entries in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Comment: Many thanks. The steps solve my problems in Ubuntu 17.10.  I found though the intrinsic thing is ubuntu is running on genuine gnome-desktop instead of ubuntu-desktop, indicated by the env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP set as 'GNOME'. If I open gnome-control-center after setting the env as  'gnome:UBUNTU, the dock item appears as that in a fresh installation does. So it is really about why GDM cannot recognize the ubuntu-desktop in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

### Fresh installation often easiest and fastest

It is often easiest and fastest to make a fresh installation instead of upgrading from a previous version.

- Backup your personal files.
- Install a fresh system.
- Install the additional program packages that you remember (that you need).
- Copy back your personal files from the backup. It helps if you use a separate **`data`** partition for your personal data.
- Later on, when you need another program package, install it. This way you will get rid of old program packages, that you will not use.