# Have icons in dock float in the center instead of left

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, dock

Is it possible to have the icons in the dock be moved to the center of the screen instead of the left side?
I have a 21:9 screen so its rather annoying to tilt your head all the time.

Please note that I'm talking about the position of the icons no the docks position. Assume that the dock is located at the bottom but it doesn't really matter.

E: This solves that: [How can I stop Ubuntu Dock from extending to the edges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970241/how-can-i-stop-ubuntu-dock-from-extending-to-the-edges)

Comment: First [move the dock to the bottom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966927/how-to-shift-side-bar-dock-to-bottom-on-ubuntu-17-10), then [make it flexible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970241/how-can-i-stop-ubuntu-dock-from-extending-to-the-edges).

Comment: @pomsky thanks the flexible part is what I was searching for. Do you want to make an answer out of that comment?