# How can I get Gnome Shell to look like Budgie without Budgie DE?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, budgie

[image: Ubuntu Budgie]

I don't want to install the Budgie Desktop Environment to avoid bugs and endless tweaks. Specifically, I like the Transparent Top Panel and the Icon pack. Is there a Budgie theme for Gnome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following.

- Change your application theme (GTK+) and shell theme to [Arc](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme) (preferably "Dark" or "Darker" variant) using *(GNOME) Tweaks*. To install the theme on Ubuntu 17.10 and later from the Universe repository run

  ```
  sudo apt install arc-theme
  ```

  Ubuntu 16.04 requires adding the repo

  ```
  sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_16.04/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:Horst3180.list"
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt install arc-theme
  ```
- Change your icon theme to [Moka](https://snwh.org/moka). For Ubuntu 17.10 and later, it's available from the Universe repository, the `pocillo-icon-theme` package will install the Moka and Faba icon-sets

  ```
  sudo apt install pocillo-icon-theme
  ```

  On older Ubuntu releases, install them from [Sam Hewitt's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) by running

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snwh/ppa
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt-get install moka-icon-theme faba-icon-theme faba-mono-icons
  ```
- Make the Ubuntu dock (on Ubuntu 17.10 and later) flexible following this Q&A: [How can I stop Ubuntu Dock from extending to the edges?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970241/how-can-i-stop-ubuntu-dock-from-extending-to-the-edges) Also perhaps reduce the size of app icons in the dock from *Settings* > *Dock*.
  For earlier Ubuntu releases, use the [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Dash to Dock](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/).
- The top bar in GNOME has dynamic transparency feature nowadays by default. If you want to have more control over its transparency use the [Dynamic Panel Transparency](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/) extension (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975343/how-do-i-make-panel-always-transparent-like-the-dock-in-ubuntu-17-10) for reference).