# Ubuntu 20.04: Switching Virtual Desktops (Workspaces) with Shortcut Keys while Using 'Workspace Matrix'

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, workspace-switcher

I am using the 'Workspace Matrix' GNOME Shell extension on Ubuntu 20.04 to work with 4 (2x2) workspaces. But to switch them, I have to first type <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, then use the arrow keys.

Is there a way to skip the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> step, i.e. switch workspaces say using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow keys</kbd>? This was possible with 'Workspace Grid' in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Only one question is allowed per question. Please don't ask multiple questions, otherwise it would be closed with the reason "needs focus". I have removed the second unrelated question, but I believe this should address that issue: https://askubuntu.com/q/970241/480481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the keybindings with `dconf-editor`.

Install:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Run `dconf-editor` and go to `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/`

Search "switch" and change the settings to your needs:

[image: dconf-editor switch workspace keybindings]

E.g.:

```
['<Super><Control>Right']
```